# NestJS with Apollo DataSource

Tags: graphql, apollo, nestjs, apollo-server

I have been trying to re-create the [Apollo tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/data-source/) with NestJS. But when I try using [`apollo-datasource-rest`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/) with NestJS, it fails when fetching data from the external data source with the following error:

```sh
[Nest] 29974   - 07/14/2020, 9:33:20 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined +125971ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
```

It seems as if the data source class in not being injected properly in the resolver, but I can't figure out why?

```js
// The data source class
@Injectable()
class LaunchAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseURL = 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/';
  }
  async getLaunchById({ launchId }) {
    return await this.get('launches', { flight_number: launchId });
  }
}

// The Nest resolver
@Resolver('launch')
@Injectable()
export class LaunchResolver {
  constructor(private readonly  launchAPI: LaunchAPI) {}

  @Query('getLaunch')
  async getLaunch(
    @Args('id') id: string
  ) {
    return await this.launchAPI.getLaunchById({ launchId: id })
  }
}

// The app module
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      dataSources,
      context: ({ req }) => {
        if (req) {
          return { headers: req.headers };
        }
      },
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.schema.ts'),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      debug: true,
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, LaunchAPI, LaunchResolver],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What's the best way to use Apollo's data source with Nest resolvers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using the `@Context` decorator on each of my resolver methods in order to grab the apollo data source services (e.g. `dataSources`), instead of injecting the data source in the resolver class. So the updated looks as following:

```js
// The Nest resolver
@Resolver('launch')
@Injectable()
export class LaunchResolver {
  @Query('getLaunch')
  async getLaunch(
    @Context('dataSources') { launchAPI }: DataSources,
    @Args('id') id: string
  ) {
    return await launchAPI.getLaunchById({ launchId: id })
  }
}

// app.module.ts

// set up any dataSources our resolvers need
const dataSources = () => ({
  launchAPI: new LaunchAPI(),
});

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      dataSources,
      context: ({ req }) => {
        if (req) {
          return { headers: req.headers };
        }
      },
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.schema.ts'),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      debug: true,
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, LaunchAPI, LaunchResolver],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: how would you resolve this if you had a service layer between your Resolver and your RestDataSource IE: Resolver --> BL Service --> RestDataSource?

Comment: There are some issues with this approach. As is, 1. You cant properly leverage DI in LaunchAPI since its added as a  data source manually and outside of the DI context.  2., LaunchAPI is setup as singleton scope. It should be request scope, but ultimately it's irrelevant since DI is entirely bypassed in this approach.

Comment: @cmd Apollo creates a new instance of the DataSource for each request; that's how it gets the  request context. But agreed, it's a bit confusing because it goes against the grain of Nest DI.